# If font not loaded then different font size when loaded form CDN specifically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fonts

I have some fonts that are loaded form **Google CDN**, i want to have a different `<body>` font size if the mentioned font is not loaded or not supported by the browser.

*What i want to achieve:-*
I want `body { font-size:16px }` to the CDN loaded font (Open Sans) 
or `body { font-size: 14px }` if the font is not loaded/not supported.

> Because all the fonts sizes are measured in `em` further down the line, if the font is not
>   loaded then the layout get disturbed with huge generic fonts.

Is there any way to achieve this with the help of **CSS** or **Javascript/jQuery** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can listen onload event on your font and detect @font-face support.
If onload or support echec you set body `font-size` to `14px`

To detect onload font you can try this:
https://github.com/patrickmarabeas/jQuery-FontSpy.js

To detect @font-face support you can try this github project:
https://github.com/paulirish/font-face-detect

Comment: Thanks for the links, i think this will support but looks like i have to compromise with some more KBs, trying with both.

Comment: @TamalDey You can also use the [Web Font Loader](https://github.com/typekit/webfontloader) to load the fonts. It will add classes to your html depending on what fonts loaded or failed.

Comment: @darthmaim that's the cool piece of info, most of the problem will be solved as far as i can see its features. Thanks :)